# Python equivalent of R's ... for matching function arguments

Tags: python, function

Within R, you can use a special argument `...` when defining functions, which is described [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#...):

> This argument will match any arguments not otherwise matched, and can be easily passed on to other functions. This is useful if you want to collect arguments to call another function, but you don’t want to prespecify their possible names.

This means that if I write a function `a` that uses another function `b` within it, I don't need to include all of the possible arguments of `b` as arguments to `a` in order to use them.

In Python, is there anything equivalent?

Comment: That sounds like something you could do with `**kwargs`, although it feels a bit sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single construct, but a combination of `*` and `**` parameters does the same, I believe.

```
def g(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

def f(x, *args, **kwargs):
    print(x)
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    print(g(*args, **kwargs))

f(9, 1, 2, z=3)
```

produces

```
9
(1, 2)
{'z': 3}
6
```

as output.

Comment: Thanks, this looks helpful. I was exploring *args/**kwargs but wasn't getting far. So if you wanted them all called by keyword you could just use **kwargs?

Comment: Yes. Python 3 makes that a little easier by allowing you to define keyword-only parameters, e.g. `def f(x, *, **kwargs)`. Now `f` can *only* be called with one positional argument, for its own positional parameter `x`. No other positional arguments are accepted, because no name was given with `*`. Any additional arguments must be keyword arguments, and they will all be gathered into `kwargs`.